# Does aluminum oxide react with rubidium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity, alkali-metals

I have rubidium vapor inside of the vacuum chamber. Inside the vacuum chamber, there are two flat stainless steel coated with aluminum oxide at temperature ~100 °C.

Since rubidium is active, I am worrying that it will interact with the aluminum oxide $\ce{Al2O3}$ coating. Any ideas?

Comment: Though I can't answer definitively, Al2O3 is used in sodium-vapor lamps that have a long lifetime. A guess would be that the surface *does* react, forming rubidium aluminate, but that it doen't penetrate rapidly.

Comment: I don't know about rubidium aluminate but a certain rubidium tetranitroaluminate does exist.

Comment: [Rubidium aluminate](https://www.americanelements.com/rubidium-aluminate) with formula $\ce{Rb_6Al_2O_6}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, rubidium aluminates do exist.
Aluminates such as $\ce{RbAlO2}$ and $\ce{Rb6Al2O6}$ are prepared at higher temperatures (above 550 °C [1]) or even from the melt.

However, alkali metal vapors at elevated temperatures act as *reducing* agent, so I wouldn't expect aluminates anyway.
On the other hand, *aluminides* such as $\ce{RbAl}$ (Zintl phase) are formed from the melt at much higher temperatures (above melting point of aluminium) and pressures exceeding atmospheric.

Since the corundum-coated plate is supposed to perform in vacuum under mild temperatures, I think it shouldn't be affected by rubidium vapors.
There is a possibility of coating embrittlement over time as rubidium diffusion occurs, but I wouldn't expect it to be an issue.

#### References

1. Schläger, M.; Hoppe, R. Darstellung und Kristallstruktur von $\ce{K6[Al2O6]}$ und $\ce{Rb6[Al2O6]}$. *Zeitschrift für anorganische und allgemeine Chemie* **1994**, 620 (5), 882–887. https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19946200522.

Comment: Maybe not aluminates alone, but you could get aluminates + intermetallics, as, $\ce{4Rb + 2Al2O3->3RbAlO2 + RbAl}$.